# Unidentifiable Vim Keymap

Tags: linux, vim, keymapping

I'm trying to get rid of a pesky keymapping in vim, namely

```
\c
```

The mapping is only loaded for latex files, so it should be related to the latex-suite. It's annoying, because it can't type `\cite` without this keymap ruining everything. I can unmap it "manually" by typing:

```
:unmap! \c
```

But this doesn't work when I put that into my `~/.vimrc` file because it says there's no such keymap.
I think this is because the keymap is loaded after `.vimrc`, although I'm not sure.

I've tried `locate` in bash to locate all files on my system that start have "vim" in their
filename, and subsequently `grep keyword $filename` to find all references to keyword that should be relevant.

The keyword I search for is "Traditional" because that's what the mapping is called (that's what I find by typing `:map!` in vim normal mode). It finds some entries that contain "Traditional" but nothing that corresponds to `\c`, except in the file:

```
~/.gnome2/gvim-sA9LOO-session.vim
```

But this file is not used by vim when starting up, as far as I know.

Anyone know any fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `:verbose map \c`.  That will tell you what file the map was defined in.

Answer (score 0):

Randy Morris:

```
:verbose map \c
```

Thanks. This is exactly a command that I could have used. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find it via google.

Anyways using it yields the following:

```
v  \c            <Plug>VisualTraditionalj
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/EnhancedCommentify.vim
n  \c            <Plug>Traditionalj
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/EnhancedCommentify.vim
```

Which is also some of the entries I found by my long method of locate and grep $keyword.

But when I search the file (EnhancedCommentify.vim)for those mappings, i.e. search for "Traditionalj" or "\c" I don't get any hits. Nor can I identify anything else that should correspond to those mapping in the file.

Comment: \ is the default mapleader, so you may want to grep for <Leader>c instead.

Comment: Thanks Randy, this did it. There seems to be some more sophisticated mappings that require different handling, and so my searches misfired. I just needed to comment out various parts referring to those mappings. Although I tried hard to figure out the solution before posting my question here, I see I still got a lot to learn about vim.